# Sending and receiving message through Signal R in ASP.net ZERO

Tags: c#, angular, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.net ZERO with Angular and ASP.net ZERO. I have configured the server side correctly but I need to receive the message from server side and subscribe to the custom message in order to invoke a routine I have called inside the subscribed method. I am sending a message manually using middle ware for now, but doesn't seem to get the message on client side. How can I subscribe to a message in client side that I have sent from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the connection (reference to the hub) client side using a service and subscribe for custom messages, when the message arrive you can fire an abp event to notify other components if you needed. for an example of this you can check the chat feature on client side, just take a look at **chat-signalr.service.ts**